# Python versions changes

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I'm currently using python 2.7.1 with some packages as shows below

```
In [4]: scipy.__version__
Out[4]: '0.17.0'

In [5]: numpy.__version__
Out[5]: '1.10.4'

In [6]: skimage.__version__
Out[6]: '0.12.3'
```

Looking into the [What's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html) page for python 3.5 i could see some new functionalities, and because this

I'm wondering if in the update of my python version i'll able to use the newer functionalities.

If i use this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

All functionalities of the packages will work in all different python versions?

**Ref**

[Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

Comment: It may depend *per package*. The biggest jump I know of was from 2.7 to 3.0, as it broke a lot of existing programs.

Comment: Was the original post edited? Looks out of sync with the answers and costing people their reputation. Stackoverflow, how do I see 'edit history' before I get penalize falsely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that programs will port painlessly from Python 2 to Python 3. Changing the ["shebang"](https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html) at the beginning of the script is completely unrelated to the porting process: all that does is to allow the shell (`bash`) to run the script through one version of Python versus another.
You should read more about the differences between Python 2 and Python 3 in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html).

Comment: I agree with your answer, i've got some read in documentation, and got more experience in python development as well.